Python - lxml - "Error in xpath expression" even if valid expression
I have the following XML structure:
   <ACES version="4.0">
        <Header>
            <Company></Company>
            <SenderName></SenderName>
            <SenderPhone></SenderPhone>
            <TransferDate></TransferDate>
            <BrandAAIAID></BrandAAIAID>
            <DocumentTitle></DocumentTitle>
            <EffectiveDate></EffectiveDate>
            <SubmissionType></SubmissionType>
            <MapperCompany></MapperCompany>
            <VcdbVersionDate></VcdbVersionDate>
            <QdbVersionDate></QdbVersionDate>
            <PcdbVersionDate>/PcdbVersionDate>
        </Header>
        <App action="A" id="1">
            <BaseVehicle id="1543"/>
            <Region id="1"/>
            <Note>Bright White</Note>
            <Note>OE Paint Code:PW7/GW7</Note>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
            <PartType id="1081"/>
            <Part>ACC0362</Part>
            <DisplayOrder>1</DisplayOrder>
        </App>
        <App action="A" id="2">
            <BaseVehicle id="1544"/>
            <Region id="1"/>
            <Note>Bright White</Note>
            <Note>OE Paint Code:PW7/GW7</Note>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
            <PartType id="1081"/>
            <Part>ACC0362</Part>
            <DisplayOrder>2</DisplayOrder>
        </App>
</ACES>

I need to match some records from an Excel file based on the: BaseVehicle id, Region id, Note[1], and Part, after which I need to update the PartType or delete the element.
The code is the following:
for _, row in aces_excel.iterrows():
    rowNo += 1
    print(rowNo)
    excelBaseVehicle = str(row['BaseVehicle'])
    excelRegion = str(int(row['Region']))
    excelPart = str(row['Part'])
    excelNote = str(row['Note'])
    excelPartTypeID = str(row['Part Term'])
    status = str(row['Diff?'])

    xpath_query = (
        f".//App[BaseVehicle/@id='{excelBaseVehicle}' and "
        f"Region/@id='{excelRegion}' and "
        f"Note[1]='{excelNote}' and "
        f"Part='{excelPart}']"
    )
  for app in root.xpath(xpath_query):
        appPartType = app.find("PartType")
        appPartType.set('id', excelPartTypeID)

I keep on getting lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Error in xpath expression  even though from all of my debugging there are no issues with it.
Could you please advise me on what is wrong?
UPDATE: Solved. The ".//" should have been only a "./"

Break down your 4 conditions and check them one by one.
Note that you define xpath_query  but you dont use it.

corrected the use of xpath_query

Your code will fail (and is vulnerable to injection attacks) if the excel data includes quotation marks in the values you are inserting into your XPath expression. Rather than using Region/@id='{excelRegion}' it's better to write Region/@id=$excelRegion and to bind a value for $excelRegion in the XPath API; however, I don't know if your XPath API allows this.

Couldn't reproduce so xpath is ok. The sample is invalid XML though due to <PcdbVersionDate>/PcdbVersionDate>. python3.9, etree.LXML_VERSION (5, 2, 2, 0)
